# Averages in Monte Carlo error propagation

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, standard-error, monte-carlo

I'm doing a Monte Carlo error propagation, so for $10^5$ iterations I:

- generate a curve $y(x)$ choosing the parameters using a multivariate gaussian distribution.
- generate a random point $x_k$ using a gaussian distribution centered in $1.32$ with a std of $0.5$
  Here showed for $100$ iterations:

[image: 100 itarations]

Then I calculate the average and standard deviation of the $y(x_k)$ and the average of the curve.
What puzzles me is that the average of the points is not on the average curve. Is that expected? I think it's not a convergence problem because I tried even with $10^7$ iteration and every time the point is above the curve in the same position.

[image: Mean]

Comment: The curve not being a line explains why.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that or suggest a reference I can look at?

Comment: Simplify by choosing a non-linear function $y=f(x)$ that has no parameters, say $y=x^2$. Then your question is equivalent to asking why $\operatorname{E}(x^2)$ is not the same as $(\operatorname{E}x)^2$. See [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality).